# Android Distinguish Between App-In-Background and Rotation Event

Tags: android, android-service, audio-recording, android-lifecycle

My fundamental problem is figuring out how to determine when my app is put into the background vs undergoing a rotation.

I have an audio recording service that is used for music recognition.  I want to intelligently manage the lifetime of this service to accomplish the following:

1. Keep the service running during lifecycle events that end up being a device rotation.
2. Stop the service when the app is put into the background (to free up the mic).

I can't override `onConfigurationChanged` because my app uses actionbar tabs with programatically added fragments and there's no way to re-inflate the fragment layouts.

What is a good way to overcome these challenges?  My best solution thus far is updating a timer in the service but I'd like to consider alternatives.  I don't like the timer because it's common to have mic contention when using voice search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `getChangingConfigurations()` or `isChangingConfigurations()` in the `onPause()`. This would tell you if the orientation is changing. If its not, then its probably going into the background.

Also, you CAN override `onCongifurationChanged()`, just make sure you call `super.onConfigurationChanged()` so that the orientation change gets handled by the framework.

Comment: Just adding that if you do this, you have to make sure to add configChanges="orientation" to any relevant Activity entries in your manifest.

Answer (score 3):

To detect your app is put into the background you can use Following Code in your Activity:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus)
Toast.makeText(this, "ON TOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (!hasFocus) {
Toast.makeText(this, "ON BACK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about why you can't override onConfigurationChanged - why exactly can't you re-inflate the fragment layouts in the same manner that you created them?

In a bound Service, shouldn't the system control running/closing your service based on whether an active app/activity is bound to it or not? Are you binding to the Service based on the Application context (persists across orientation changes) or the Activity context (transient)? Maybe try switching that in your code and see if you get the behavior you're seeking.

EDIT: Maybe you need a hybrid solution of the onStartCommand/stopService *and* bindService. Started services seem to allow for persistence beyond the activity lifecycle, but also allow you to pass state data from one bound Activity to the next (via onBind/onRebind). Not sure if that data would help with your fragments, but you could at least pass a flag that tells you whether this is a "fresh" vs "recycled" activity.

I haven't used Services yet myself, but maybe a closer examination of the [Bound Service Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle) would help.

Comment: Because a fragment does not own the view like an activity does.  The fragment passes its view to the activity parent in onCreateView to be placed in the view hierarchy.  Yes my service is bound but I unbind when the activity is destroyed, and rotating the device causes the event chain onPause->onStop->onDestroy.